# RSA encryption using public key from .pem file

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption, evp-cipher

I am using RSA_public_encrypt function to send the encrypted data to socket. I am reading the public key  from .PEM file using "pkey = PEM_read_PUBKEY(f, NULL, NULL, NULL);"  function.
'pkey' retrieved from above function is of type EVP_PKEY* which I can not use in function RSA_public_encrypt. (RSA_public_encrypt uses RSA* type key)

How to convert EVP_PKEY *pkey to RSA *rsa?

Comment: which language are you using???

Comment: I am doing this in C language

Answer (score 1):

Use `RSA *EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(EVP_PKEY *pkey)` to get RSA type key from EVP_PKEY.

Example:

```
EVP_PKEY    *evp;
RSA         *pubkey

evp = ...; /* some way to get the public key */
pubkey = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(evp);
if (pubkey == NULL) {
    /* error handling */
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to free the ```RSA*``` by callint ```RSA_free``` !